# gtk ERROR MESSAGE Key file contains line which is not a key-value pair, group, or comment

Tags: gtk

The problem I'm having with this function is that it gets the following error if there is an error in the gtk keyfile. It literally jumps out of the function dumping back to the command line.

ERROR MESSAGE Key file contains line ""./icon.ico"" which is not a key-value pair, group, or comment

iconFile=

"./icon.ico"

But this is ok and it works without getting an error

iconFile="./icon.ico"

I've searched the internet but unable to fine anything relating to this error. I tried running it through gdb and valgrind but was unable to spot an error.

Can someone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong?

```
// *** config.c ***
//  gcc -Wall -Wextra -o config config.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <glib.h>
//#include <stdio.h>

#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

extern gchar *__progname;

int myErrorCheck(gchar **myData);

// create / get CONFIG file configuration
int main(int argc, gchar *argv[])
{

// THESE ARE CONFIG FILE DEFAULT SETTINGS
// MPD HOST SETTINGS
    gchar *mpdHostname    = "localhost";
    gint mpdPortnumber  = 6600;
    gint mpdTimeout     = 30000;

// PLAYLIST SETTINGS
    gchar *rowFont   = "\"Bold 16\"";
    gchar *viewColor = "\"medium slate blue\"";
    gchar *textColor = "\"black\"";

// OTHER SETTINGS
    gchar *windowTitle      = "Selecet MPD Playlist";
    gchar *iconFile     = "\"./icon.ico\"";

// COMMENTS
// this comment goes above MpdHostSettings group header
    gconstpointer HostSettingsComment = " These are the MPD Host parameters for this executable.";

// this comment goes above PlayListSettings  group  header
    gconstpointer PlayListSettingsComment = " These are the MPD Playlist executable parameters.\n Enclose each parameter in quotes (\"\")";

// this comment goes above windowTitle in Other group header
    gconstpointer windowTitleComment = " This is the window title.";

// this comment goes above iconFile in Other group header
    gconstpointer iconFileComment = " This is the window icon.";

// *** End of THESE ARE CONFIG FILE DEFAULT SETTINGS ***

    GKeyFile *key_file;
    GError *error;

    key_file = g_key_file_new();
    error = NULL;

    gchar *cfgFile;
    gchar   *confPath;


// *** COPY LOWER CASE __progname AS UPPER CASE into upper__progname
    gchar *upper__progname = g_ascii_strup(__progname, strlen(__progname));

// *** TEST or CREATE (if needed) the user config file PATHNAME (should be ~/.config/PROGNAME)

// build the config path string
    confPath = g_strconcat(g_get_user_config_dir(),"/", upper__progname,NULL);

    cfgFile = g_strconcat(confPath,"/", __progname,".conf",NULL);

// Does the config path exist? This IS a CRITICAL error.
    if(access(confPath,F_OK | R_OK)) {
    fprintf (stderr, "WARNING: Error opening config path %s : %s. Line number %d\n", confPath, strerror(errno), __LINE__);

// if possible create PATH directory if it does not exist
    if(mkdir (confPath,S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IROTH | S_IXOTH) == -1) {
        g_print("Line %d\n", __LINE__);
// should it for some reason not be created
        fprintf (stderr, "Critical: Error creating config path %s : %s. Line number %d\n", confPath, strerror(errno), __LINE__);
        exit(errno);
    }

// WRITE THE DEFAULT CONFIGURATION TO FILE IF CONF FILE HAS TO BE CREATED
// MPD HOST SETTINGS
    g_key_file_set_string(key_file,  "MpdHostSettings", "mpdHostname",   mpdHostname);
    g_key_file_set_integer(key_file, "MpdHostSettings", "mpdPortnumber", mpdPortnumber);
    g_key_file_set_integer(key_file, "MpdHostSettings", "mpdTimeout",    mpdTimeout);

// PLAYLIST SETTINGS
    g_key_file_set_string(key_file, "PlayListSettings", "rowFont",   rowFont);
    g_key_file_set_string(key_file, "PlayListSettings", "viewColor", viewColor);
    g_key_file_set_string(key_file, "PlayListSettings", "textColor", textColor);

// OTHER PARAMETERS
    g_key_file_set_string(key_file, "OtherSettings", "windowTitle",  windowTitle);
    g_key_file_set_string(key_file, "OtherSettings", "iconFile",  iconFile);

// COMMENTS

    g_key_file_set_comment(key_file, "PlayListSettings", NULL, PlayListSettingsComment, NULL);
    g_key_file_set_comment(key_file, "MpdHostSettings", NULL, HostSettingsComment, NULL);
    g_key_file_set_comment(key_file, "OtherSettings", "windowTitle", windowTitleComment, NULL);
    g_key_file_set_comment(key_file, "OtherSettings", "iconFile", iconFileComment, NULL);
//*********************************************************************

// SAVE them to to file
    g_key_file_save_to_file (key_file, cfgFile, &error);
    }  // End of CREATE CFG FILE

// LOAD THE KEYS FROM CONF FILE IF THEIR IS NO ERROR
    if(!g_key_file_load_from_file(key_file, cfgFile, G_KEY_FILE_KEEP_COMMENTS, &error))
    {
    printf("ERROR MESSAGE %s\n", error->message);
    g_debug("%s", error->message);
    g_key_file_free (key_file);
    return 1;
    }

// MPD HOST PARAMETERS
    mpdHostname    = g_key_file_get_string(key_file, "MpdHostSettings", "mpdHostname",   &error);
    mpdPortnumber = g_key_file_get_integer(key_file, "MpdHostSettings", "mpdPortnumber", &error);
    mpdTimeout = g_key_file_get_integer(key_file, "MpdHostSettings", "mpdTimeout",  &error);

// MPD PLAYLIST PARAMETERS
    rowFont    = g_key_file_get_string(key_file, "PlayListSettings", "rowFont",   &error);
    viewColor = g_key_file_get_string(key_file, "PlayListSettings", "viewColor",   &error);
    textColor  = g_key_file_get_string(key_file, "PlayListSettings", "textColor",   &error);
    windowTitle = g_key_file_get_string(key_file, "OtherSettings", "windowTitle", &error);
    iconFile  = g_key_file_get_string(key_file, "OtherSettings", "iconFile",   &error);

// *** PRINT THESE VARIABLES ***
// MPD HOST SETTINGS
    g_print("mpdHostname %s\n",mpdHostname);
    g_print("mpdPortnumber %d\n", mpdPortnumber)  ;
    g_print("mpdTimeout %d\n", mpdTimeout);

// PLAYLIST SETTINGS
    g_print("rowFont %s\n", rowFont);
    g_print("viewColor %s\n", viewColor);
    g_print("textColor %s\n",  textColor);
    g_print("windowTitle %s\n", windowTitle);
    g_print("iconFile %s\n", iconFile);


    g_key_file_free (key_file);
    g_free(error);
    g_free(cfgFile);
    g_free(mpdHostname );

//g_free(mpdPortnumber );
//g_free(mpdTimeout );

    g_free(rowFont );
    g_free(viewColor );
    g_free(textColor );
    g_free(windowTitle );
    g_free(iconFile );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First question comment: It is great that you've provided an example of the problem, and in future it would be more useful if the example just focussed on the error, not the whole program. Your program didn't contain the line that is in error, it appears to be from a different file.

Answer (score 0):

I have found my mistake.

The problem is in the "error->message" (GError) that gets set by the "g_key_file_load_from_file()" function in my error check routine.

```
 if(!g_key_file_load_from_file(key_file, cfgFile, G_KEY_FILE_NONE, &error))
{
    printf("ERROR MESSAGE %s\n", error->message);
    g_debug("%s", error->message);
    g_key_file_free (key_file);
    return 1;
}
```

Thus if there is an error in the conf file or conf file does not exist then "g_key_file_load_from_file" returns 1 and gracefully exits the function. I failed to realize that if an error occurs anywhere in the conf file it will also be flagged here.